# Multiple Views for a single ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datatemplate

### Issue

---

I have a number of buttons in my `WPF Window` which when clicked need to change the view on the `Window` but keep the same `ViewModel`. Yesterday I tried using `ControlTemplate` for this but people mentioned I was better using a `DataTemplate.`

I need the binding to happen Via the `ViewModel` as well as I need to do some checks to see if the user can access the view.

### Code

---

This is some of the code i started to write but I feel like its incorrect.

Here is the `DataTemplate` that I have defined in my view in `Window.Resources`:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="panel1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="110*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="190*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="110*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="202*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="109*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="74*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="12*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="11*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="38*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Label Content="Video Set:" Foreground="#e37e6e" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding VideoSet}" Height="25" Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <TextBlock Foreground="#e37e6e" FontSize="12" Text="You currently do not have a video set. Please click the button below to add a video. Please note you will not be able to create an On Demand presentation without a media file selected. " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
            <Button Style="{StaticResource loginButton}" Command="{Binding ScreenBack}" Foreground="White" Content="Add Video" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></Button>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then I tried to use a `ContentPresenter` and bind to the `DataTemplate`:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
```

Now I want to be able to bind different `DataTemplates` to the `ContentPresenter` Via the `ViewModel`, can anyone help me with this issue?

EDIT:

I can bind the `ContentPresenter` to the `DataTemplate` through the static resource like below:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource panel1}" Content="{StaticResource panel1}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
```

The `DataTemplate` like below:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="panel1">

</DataTemplate>
```

But how can i change the `ControlPresenter` binding from the `ViewModel`?

EDIT:

Here is my code cycle:

So here are the two DataTemplates:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelA}">
     <TextBlock Foreground="#e37e6e" FontSize="12" Text="You currently do not have a video set. Please click the button below to add a video. Please note you will not be able to create an On Demand presentation without a media file selected. " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelB}">
     <TextBlock Foreground="#e37e6e" FontSize="12" Text="NEWWWWWWWWWWYou" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
</DataTemplate>
```

The my ContentControl:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}" />
```

I defined my DataContext in the code behind:

```
WizardViewModel _wizardViewModel = new WizardViewModel();
this.DataContext = _wizardViewModel;
```

In the WizardViewModel i have:

```
namespace Podia2016.ViewModels
{
    public class WizardViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public object SelectedViewModel { get; set; }

        ViewModelA s = new ViewModelA();
        ViewModelB d = new ViewModelB();

        public WizardViewModel()
        {
            SelectedViewModel = s;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel"); 

        }

        //BC - BINDS TO CHANGE LECTURE.
        public ICommand Next
        {
            get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(Next_Click); }
        }

        private void Next_Click(object obj)
        {
            SelectedViewModel = d;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel");  
        }
    }

public class ViewModelA : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //BC - DEFAULT ONPROPERTYCHANGED EVENT.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ViewModelA()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the standard OnPropertyChanged Event Method 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModelB : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //BC - DEFAULT ONPROPERTYCHANGED EVENT.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ViewModelB()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the standard OnPropertyChanged Event Method 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What are your expected results, and what happened when you tried to use the ContentPresenter to bind to the DataTemplate?

Comment: @Tyress I just get a message inside the ContentPresenter saying 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate' but that isn't through the ViewModel as i'm unsure what to put in that.

Comment: @BenClarke see my answer

Comment: @BenClarke and how are you setting your ViewModel as your DataContext?

Comment: @Tyress In the code behind i just set the DataContext like this `this.DataContext = _wizardViewModel;`

Comment: Ben, please stop forcing tags into question titles. That's what the tags section is for. Read the FAQ on usage of tags http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging. Only put "tags" into question title if it's a natural part of the question. Users experienced with one of the tags are monitoring them and will answer to it. `The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title.`

Comment: @Tseng What tag doesn't relate to my question?

Comment: @BenClarke: It's not about the tags in the tag section. It's the title of the question. Your former title was "MVVM WPF - Multiple Views Single ViewModel". The "MVVM WPF - " is not natural part of the question title, it is forced tags into the title. You should avoid that, unless it's `organic to the conversational tone`. For example: Bad: `MVVM UWP MVVMLight - How to bind a property?`Good: `How to bind a property in an UWP application using MVVM Light`. Now "MVVM Light" and "UWP" is not only a forced tag, but part of a organic sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data templating is much simpler to use (compared to your attempt):

- create sub viewmodels, one for each sub view you want to have

```
// could have base class, may have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, etc.
public class ViewModelA { }
public class ViewModelB
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; }
}
...

public object SelectedViewModel { get; set; }
```

- define data templates

```
<SomeContainer.Resources>
    <!-- using user control -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelA}">
        <local:UserControlA />
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- or like this -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelB}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
            <Button .../>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

- Bind content control to a property which select sub viewmodel

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}" />
```

- control what to display by changing selected sub viewmodel:

```
var a = new ViewModelA();
var b = new ViewModelB() { SomeProperty = "Test" };

// display a - will display UserControlA content in ContentControl
SelectedViewModel = a;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedViewModel));

// display b - will display text and button in ContentControl
SelectedViewModel = b;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedViewModel));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your second code snippet I get an error 'Local is not defined'

Comment: You should have `local` defined in your window/usercontrol xaml automatically. If you don't, then just add it, e.g. `<Window x:Class="SomeNamespace.SomeClass" ... xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace" ... />

Comment: So the code runs but the `DataTemplate's` are not displaying. Do the `ViewModelA` and `ViewModelB` class need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: I adding PropertyChanged and still doesn't show anything?

Comment: Typically they have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but there can be a case when you simply display static content (no bindings), then this viewmodel doesn't have to implement (it can, but it's not used then).

Comment: I have added the INotifyPropertyChanged but the controls are still not appearing. The code is getting hit in the ViewModel though.

Comment: Can you show your code somehow? E.g. [edit question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35647896/edit) and add there your failed attempt. My answer is very generic, it's not tailored to solve your exact issue, only to show the general idea of (shall I say *typical*?) data templating to switch view content.

Comment: I figured it out! The reason was because i didn't set the grid.column + grid.row on the ContentControl. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Store `DataTemplate` as property of your `ViewModel`. Access the DataTemplate from `ResourceDictionary` to store in your property.

Bind `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{Binding template1}" .../>`

**How to access ResourceDictionary from code :**

If you have in your WPF project an ResourceDictionary that you use to define resources you can create an instance of it from code like this:

```
ResourceDictionary res = Application.LoadComponent(
 new Uri("/WpfApplication1;component/MyDataTemplateCollection.xaml", 
 UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) as ResourceDictionary;
```

Where WpfApplication1 is name of your assembly and MyDataTemplateCollection.xaml is name of your ResourceDictionary.

Another way is to use the code-behind for the resource dictionary.

Add x:Class to your ResourceDictionary:

Add class `MyDataTemplateCollection.xaml.cs` as your code-behind for the ResourceDictionary.

The code behind class looks like so:

```
partial class MyDataTemplateCollection: ResourceDictionary
{
   public MyDataTemplateCollection()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }     
}
```

Usage :

```
ResourceDictionary res = new MyDataTemplateCollection();
```

Comment: Would be better just store DataTemplate key and write converter from name to DataTemplate

Comment: @AnjumSkhan I have never done this before and am unsure on how to implement both of your suggestions i.e Storing DataTemplate as a property of ViewModel etc...

Comment: @BenClarke Your ViewModel class cannot contain DataTemplate, then how will you load it ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan So the ViewModel cannot bind to the DataTemplate? If so, is this even possible?

Comment: 100% possible. Create a property of type DataTemplate in your VM. Then this `DataTemplate` would need to have some value. Bring this value by loading it from ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Very interesting idea, actually. You can associate a View with your ViewModel directly without DataTemplate. You can set multiple Views to multiple ViewModel's properties. Properties can be typed or not depending on your needs.